# Sections not lining up to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

[image]

I'm trying to line these two sections up to the bottom of a canvas right now, but one is always lower than the other, depending on how big the section is. 
This is the CSS right now. I want to line them both up at the top.

```css
#canvas {
  display: block;
}

#info {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-overflow: clip;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#commands {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px auto;
}

#devTools {
  width: 1500px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
}

section {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--TODO: Adjust the size of the canvas to fit the window-->
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1500" , height="600"></canvas>

  <!--TODO: Create buttons for all devtools under the canvas-->
  <!--TODO: Make a container for all devtools under the canvas, then add all the functionality to it after-->
  <div id="devTools">
    <section id="info">
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Creature Number: </p>
      <p>Selected: </p>
    </section>

    <section id="commands">
      <p>Commands</p>
      <button class="button">Click me!</button>
      <button class="button">Click me!</button>
      <button class="button">Click me!</button>
      <button class="button">Click me!</button>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML also?

Comment: Could you please post a *complete* and *working* piece of your code, so that we can **run** and test it ?

Comment: Yup, just changed and added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `section` - that's how your vertically *align* `inline-block` elements - see demo below:

```css
#canvas {
  display: block;
}

#info {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-overflow: clip;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#commands {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px auto;
}

#devTools {
  width: 1500px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
}

section {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--TODO: Adjust the size of the canvas to fit the window-->
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1500" , height="600"></canvas>

  <!--TODO: Create buttons for all devtools under the canvas-->
  <!--TODO: Make a container for all devtools under the canvas, then add all the functionality to it after-->
  <div id="devTools">
    <section id="info">
      <p>Info</p>
      <p>Creature Number: </p>
      <p>Selected: </p>
    </section>

    <section id="commands">
      <p>Commands</p>
      <button class="button">Click me!</button>
      <button class="button">Click me!</button>
      <button class="button">Click me!</button>
      <button class="button">Click me!</button>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `vertical-align:top` in both class **#info** and **#commands**